# Representing a lookup table in SQL Server and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

We are sending updates on the status of an avatar to an external service via their API.

The Avatar:

```
ID  
Name
Age
Nationality
Status
```

There are 4 statuses we can send:

```
(A) Alive
(D) Dead
(C) Injured
(U) Unknown
```

The characters in brackets are how the statuses are stored in the external system - and we must send them ID & Status in that format.

We need to store these in SQL Server, so we'd have the primary key of the status table in the avatar table.

We also need to represent the status in C# code. It's unlikely the status will ever change - so an enum or dictionary would (I think) be an appropriate way to represent the statuses to make them clear in C# code.

We can add an int primary key to the status table, then have a single letter representation (as sent to the external system), and the full name.

Or we could set the primary key to a char(1) as the letter - and store that in the Status column of the Avatar table.

The former could be an enum - the latter a dictionary in C#.

Are there any normalisation problems with either approach. Are there any issues with either approach in object oriented terms.

What is the best practice in both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is primarily opinion based; and there is no universal answer as to what is best.

My recommendation is based on the principles of *Seperation of Concerns*. I skeep the "data" as compact as possible within both the Database Layer as well as the Application Layer. The "Presentation Layer" is where I work with the *Human Readable* formats. This parallels working with DateTime values; Sql Server stores it as an 8 byte number, and .Net works with as a number. It is only when we want to see it that we should use the `To...String()` family to get into the presentation format.

Now for your particular scenario.

**ID** I generally recommend an integer based format and I would most likely SQL Server's `IDENTITY()` for populating that.

**Name** No real debate here; string in .Net and nvarchar in Sql Server. I would probably put a limit on this to be less than say 100 characters.

**Age** The question here about Age is if the character will age or not. If the character is going to age in real-time, this would not be an integer and would be a DateTime based value for DOB, and the application layer would calculate age based upon this.

**Nationality** Most likely this would best be served as a numeric value in the application and database layers. Presentation could use a dictionary or similar lookup for display.

**Status** As you suggested, keep it a number until it's time to display; enum, dictionary, etc would be fine for lookup.

I also try to do have the db schema match the class properties, with the smallest types (bool, int) at hoisted up top and the longer strings at the end.

Comment: thanks so - the meat of my question is - store the primary key of the statuses table as an int or a char(1)? If it's an int it will require some additional looking to change it to the char(1) that will be required for sending to the external system - though an int PK is generally better..?!

Comment: @niico - My recommendation would be TinyInt, same storage size in SQL as CHAR(1) but a lot easier on the PK and indexes (clusterd or not).

Comment: So that perf is more important than readability? Would this perf only be relevant when performing a join between the avatar and status table?

Comment: Data storage and Application logic should be working with smallest possible data type. Presentation layer is where you readability becomes a factory. With such a limited amount of values, you will most likely memorize them anyways